# How to escape spaces in systemd unit files?

Tags: service, systemd, escaping

My unit file looks like this (already attempted to escape spaces as `\x20` like the docs say):

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/cobra/my\x20service/
ExecStart=/home/cobra/my\x20service/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but when attempting to start it, it fails with the following message:

```
Failed at step CHDIR spawning /home/cobra/my service/start.sh: No such file or directory
myservice.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
```

Giving the path from this error message to `stat` returns:

```
  File: ‘/home/cobra/my service/start.sh’
  Size: 280             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 903h/2307d      Inode: 4718912     Links: 1
Access: (0754/-rwxr-xr--)  Uid: ( 1000/   cobra)   Gid: ( 1000/   cobra)
Access: 2015-05-24 22:42:12.702657594 +0200
Modify: 2015-03-27 22:28:05.682531000 +0100
Change: 2015-05-24 22:40:58.830298787 +0200
 Birth: -
```

I cannot remove the spaces from the file name as the service I'm attempting to run requires them for some reason.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried backslash space ("\ ")  like the shell?

Comment: @Matt Yes, same error as above, except the backslash is visible in the path presented in the errormessage.

Comment: It seems that spaces are used as a way of separating arguments.  And googling this returns some ugly workarounds.  Can you change the path? otherwise what about trying a non-space separated symbolic link as the path name which points to the real directory?

Comment: Well I did find a tool called systemd-escape which allows you to create paths.  It seems / gets changed to dash.

Comment: Did you figure out how to get WorkingDirectory to work with spaces? Nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 11):

The correct way to generate paths in systemd is to use systemd-escape.

i.e.

```
~$ systemd-escape --path "/home/cobra/my service/start.sh"
home-cobra-my\x20service-start.sh
```

Yes `/` gets replaced with `-`

Comment: in my case I only needed to escape the path for the `WorkingDirectory` setting using the `systemd-escape` command before my service worked. is it best practice to escape paths used in the `ExecStart` setting with the command as well or does is it fine to just use quotes as long as it works?

Comment: I would use quotes if possible.  But failing that, this tool.  In the end you need to try something that works.   In my opinion, systemd-escape is a funny tool that produces pretty odd looking escape sequences (dash for slash?? etc).  The systemd team made some odd choices down the road.  This is one of them.

Comment: In my case, paths returned by systemd-escape did not work. Replacing spaces with \x20 and no quotes worked.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious thing to do is to use double quotes.

```
ExecStart="/home/cobra/my service/start.sh"
```

You also should get rid of the start.sh script and move any necessary logic into the unit.

Comment: Putting quotes around it like you suggested makes the service fail completely: `Failed to start myservice.service: Unit myservice.service failed to load: Invalid argument.`

Comment: The underlying error message seems to be `Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: "/home/cobra..."` `myserivce.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.`

Comment: Turns out quoting the executable path is supported since systemd version 218-147 (2014-12-19) and debian jessie is still sitting on 215-17. I just wrote the debian people a bugreport, we'll see what comes of it.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Good luck with that. Of course I would never advise using Debian at all, but that's another discussion...

Answer (score 1):

For spaces in ExecStart, there is an open bug report.[1] The workaround is to use `/usr/bin/env` followed by the path in quotes. Example:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/env "/path/with spaces/executable"`

The canonical —but not so nice— solution is to use `systemd-escape`.

`systemd-escape --path "/path/with spaces/executable"`

> [1] https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2132